# Intel SASWT4I SAS/SATA Controller 

Tags: storage, sata, sas, controller

I want to assemble a cheap storage sytem based on the Norco RPC-4020 Case.

When searching for controllers I found this one:

[Intel® RAID Controller SASWT4I](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/prodbrief/RAID_SASWT4I_prodbrief.pdf)

This is a quote form the Spec Sheet:

> Scalability. Supports up to 122
>   physical devices in SAS mode which is
>   ideal  for employing JBODs (Just a
>   Bunch Of Disks) or up to 14 devices in
>   RAID  0, 1, 1E/10E mode through direct
>   connect device attachment or through 
>   expander backplane support.

Does that mean I can attach 14 SATA drives directly to the controller using SFF-8087 - 4x SATA breakout cables?

That would be nice because then I can choose a mainboard that has 6 Onboard SATA and i can connect all 20 bays while only spending 155$ on the controller and like another 100$ on cables.

Would that work? And why is it 14 and not 16 when there are 4 Ports?

I am really confused about all the breakout/fanout/(edge-)expanding/multiplying/channel stuff...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand the card only has 4 sata ports but you can use SAS drives if you have the right connectors (presumably SAS-> sata).

To use more than 4 of either drive you would need to connect a sas expander to the card using a reverse SATA to SFF-8087 breakout cable and then connect the extra drives to the expander